# Fill PDF form and send filled form with email using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have one PDF form which can be filled manually.

I want to fill it with data dynamically and send this PDF with email.

Which dll you advice to use and how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

So lets start,
First using NuGet add iTextSharp to your project.[Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)
Lets continue :

Every field in editable PDF have own name.After learning this field names.

```
private static void FillPDFForm()
        { 
                // Original File
                const string pdfTemplate="Uploads\CV.PDF";
                // New file which will be created after fillin PDF
                var newFile ="Uploads\FilledCV.PDF"
                var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                    newFile, FileMode.Create));
                var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                // So one of our fields in PDF is FullName I am filling it with my full name
                pdfFormFields.SetField("FullName", "Vuqar Qasimov");                    

                // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
                // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits

                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
                pdfStamper.Close();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Bingo we already created file lets attach it to email and send it

```
  public void SendEmailWithAttachment()
        {
            var objMailMessage = new MailMessage("EnterFromEmailAddress", "ReceiverEmailAddress")
            {
                Subject = "EnterEmailSubject",
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = "EnterEmailBody"
            };
            //You can add more attachments
            objMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("EnterAttachmentLocationPath")); 
            var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
            var login = new NetworkCredential("SenderEmail","SenderEmailPAssword");
            smtp.Credentials = login;
            smtp.Port =  587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true; 
            smtp.Send(objMailMessage); 
        }
```

- I used office 365 as email .if you using different email accounts you may have to change port or another credentials.
- From my experience rather than design PDF files using iTextSharp or another packages better to design it with third part applications and fill it with iTextSharp.It will look more better and will take less time.

Comment: I see that you link to [a version of iTextSharp that should no longer be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially). I have corrected the link. You can see that the version you point to is dead (it dates from 2009 and the project hasn't been updated since 2011). My link points to a version that is actively maintained.

Comment: `PdfStamper` no longer exists.